# Is there a way in ggplot to have 2 different variables in same x axis labels with different font type?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

I'm trying to get different fonts in the x axis labeling of ggplot. I can see from the following link: [X-axis tick labels different font size and font face ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59634326/x-axis-tick-labels-different-font-size-and-font-face-ggplot) that it's likely bquote and atop. However, I'm not entirely sure how to go about this.

The following is some code also from stack overflow here: [ggplot displaying expression in x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758050/ggplot-displaying-expression-in-x-axis)

```
group_name = sprintf("A[%i*x]", rep(1:4,each=2))
group_name3 = sprintf("A[%j*x]", rep(1:4,each=2))

make_labels2 <- function(value) {
  x <- as.character(value)
  do.call(expression, lapply(x, function(y) bquote(atop(bold(.(y)), "this"~italic("degree")~x))))
}


mydata2 <- data.frame(mygroup = group_name, 
                      mygroup3 = group_name3,
                      mysubgroup = factor(c("Yes", "No"), 
                                          levels = c("Yes", "No")), 
                      value = c(60,40,90,10,55,45,88,12))

ggplot(mydata2, aes(mygroup, value, fill = mysubgroup)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", width = 0.5, stat = "identity")+ 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = make_labels2)
```

I want to be able to use group_name3 and just concatenate it onto the group_name. Struggling to find the best way. With group_name3 not being bold.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
group_name = sprintf("A[%i*x]", rep(1:4,each=2))
group_name3 = sprintf("A[%i*y]", rep(1:4,each=2))

make_labels2 <- function(value) {
  x <- as.character(value)
  #do.call(expression, lapply(x, function(y) bquote(atop(bold(.(y)), "this"~italic("degree")~x)) ))
  do.call(expression, lapply(x, function(y) bquote(atop(bold(.(strsplit(y,split="_")[[1]][[1]]))~"_"~italic(.(strsplit(y,split="_")[[1]][[2]])), "this"~italic("degree")~x)) ))
}

mydata2 <- data.frame(mygroup = group_name, 
                      mygroup3 = group_name3,
                      mysubgroup = factor(c("Yes", "No"), 
                                          levels = c("Yes", "No")), 
                      value = c(60,40,90,10,55,45,88,12))
mydata2$mygrp2 <- paste0(mydata2$mygroup,"_",mydata2$mygroup3)

ggplot(mydata2, aes(mygrp2, value, fill = mysubgroup)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", width = 0.5, stat = "identity")+ 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = make_labels2)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks @YBS this is very helpful. How could I make mygroup3 not bold in this? So the first part is bold but the second part isn't. Is there something I need to do in lapply for that?

Comment: Yes.  Please see the updated code and modify `lapply` as necessary.

Comment: This works great. Just another quick addition, how could I wrap the first variable so it's on multiple lines. i.e. for a string it would be str_wrap(mygroup, width = 2). Struggling to find a way for this when using an expression. Any ideas?

Comment: Please ask new issues as new questions so that others can help you.

Comment: Thanks have done, link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66352642/is-there-a-way-to-wrap-an-expression-on-multiple-lines-in-r